# Add String to ImageView Object Android

Tags: android, tags, android-imageview, android-view

I need to attach a String into the ImageView object so that I could do something like `imgView1.getString()` and it would return it.

I know there is `getTags` and `setTags` but from my understanding that just uses ints.

Thank you

Comment: `getTag()` returns an Object which you can cast to a string.

Answer (score 3):

Just complementing @dharms answer, you can set any `Object` as the tag for the `ImageView`, whether is an int, double, String, etc.

So in your case you can do this:

`imgView1.setTag("some_string")`

and then to retrieve it just do:

`String someString = (String) imgView1.getTag();`